# How to display only content assigned to a user?

Tags: views, 6, entities

I have created a content type with a CCK field named 'executor' of 'User reference' type. So the admin can select a different user as an executor in creating content.

I want to create a page using views to display all tasks a user is assigned to as executor. But I don't know what I should put in fields and filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create views by filtering the content type which you want to list in there.

Then add a argument in the view, which will be the field you are using to reference the user in your content type.

Supply UID of currently logged in user as default arguments & your content will be filtered for logged in user.

User will see all the fields values added by you on the page, fields are totally dependent upon your selection which you can add in views.